# unable to import com.google.android.maps.* in android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, import

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
```

I have to import the above packages into my app. I am not able to do it. I tried installing Google APIs from SDK manager. Still it shows me errors.
Plus I added the following dependency in my build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Still I am not able to import.

Here is my build.gralde file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.incrediblemachine.andhiv"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

}
```

my manifest file is as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.incrediblemachine.andhiv"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!--  Add Google Map Library -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- SinglePlaceActivity -->
        <activity android:name=".SinglePlaceActivity" android:label="Place Details">
        </activity>

        <!-- PlacesMapActivity -->
        <activity android:name=".PlacesMapActivity" android:label="Near Places Map View">

        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Access Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: is your `google play services` updated?

Comment: try specifying the exact version of it like this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`. Also, check if `Google repositories` is updated / installed

Comment: google repositories are installed. this dependency didnt help

Comment: @BajiraoShinde the symbol maps cannot be resolved

Comment: post you manifest here

Comment: @BajiraoShinde.. i have edited the question

Comment: mak sure you have installed Google Play Service Library from your Android SDK MANAGER

Comment: yes i have installed it @BajiraoShinde

Comment: you are not able to import is this what your error is right ??

Comment: its this package you have to import
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;

Comment: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'` this dependency is for Google map v2

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Put below dependency in your build.gradle resides in application module directory.

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    }
```

Step 2. Save the changes and click **Sync Project** with Gradle Files in the toolbar.

Comment: In that case please post your full gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

> symbol maps cannot be resolved

The compiler cannot find the class. This means that the class has not been imported properly

**Don't**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

**Do**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
or //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Sync`** your Project .

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.incrediblemachine.andhiv.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: @JaganP Restart your project .

Comment: still no luck with that

Comment: how do i choose target name for application in android studio. the answer for that question is for eclipse

Comment: @JaganP at first add `import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;`

Comment: @JaganP same problem for `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'` ?

Comment: whats your `build classpath` version ?

Comment: build classpath version??
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

Comment: call `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' `  or `1.5.0`

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: Manifest .above `application`

Comment: @JaganP Let me feedback please .

Comment: @JaganP any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Manually add that dependency instead. Do these steps:

1. Click **File**, then **Project Structure**
2. under **modules**, you'll see a folder named **app**
3. access the said folder in step 2, then you will see multiple tabs. Go and enter **Dependencies**.
4. You will see a green **plus sign button**, click and and choose `Library Dependency`.
5. Enter `com.google.android.gms:play-services:+` and click `ok`. Then click another `ok` and wait for the gradle to recompile

Comment: Clean the project. Re-open Android Studio. If these steps failed, try starting a new project then add the dependency manually. This is to confirm that the process works in a **clean** project but for some reasons, it doesn't work in your current project.